# Netbeans 8.0.2 java autocompletion not working

Tags: java, autocomplete, netbeans-8

Java code autocompletion is not working with Netbeans 8.0.2. I did not try it with any other langauage.

- OS  - Windows  7  x64
- jdk - Java 8u45 64 bit

Netbeans version - NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)

Removing the cache directory from "C:/Users/username/Appdata/Local/netbeans" did not work for me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did or didn't work? Also please consider to report a bug to the netbeans developer team.

Comment: For example for a JButton the addActionListener method usually will autocomplete if I type "add" like that all methods for any API

Comment: Sorry It was a syntactical blunder from my part. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, that you found the solution. This saves time for the Stackoverflow-Community. Could you maybe also post an answer to your own question? I know, it sounds a bit weird, but it could help others, that might face this, same issue.